# jquery autocomplite : как изменить элемент в зависимости от возвращённого результата?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Суть проблемы: Есть два Input, к первому подключен autocomplite с выбором улицы из mysql, во втором должна выводится цена в зависимости от выбранной улицы. В таблице хранятся значения street и city, где street содержит имя улицы, а city 0 или 1 в зависимости от принадлежности улицы к городу или пригороду. Не могу понять как  организовать изменение второго inputa.

Comment: Откуда цена должна браться?

Comment: ТК всего 2 варианта цены, я думал получать значение city и на в зависимости от его значения присваивать цену на клиенте. Если принципиально, можно хранить цену в базе и оттуда её вытаскивать.